# How to use a file from public_html folder to any folder?

Tags: php

I want to use `dbconnect.php` file from `public_html` folder to `public_html/profile/`. I am trying to do this with this code in `public_html/profile/index.php` file:

```
<?php include'/dbconnect.php'; ?>
```

but it give an error.

Comment: What is absolute path of dbconnect?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php include'../dbconnect.php'; ?>
```

Though, the best way to write it is:

```
<?php require_once("../dbconnect.php"); ?>
```

If dbconnect.php is in your `public_html` folder and the file in which you are using the include is in the `public_html/profile/` folder, you need to use `../` to get to the parent folder.

Putting it like you have would have Linux looking for dbconnect.php in the root of the operating system; which obviously, it's not there!

So whenever you want to go back a folder, or 2, you can do stuff like `../../file.php` or even go back, then enter another folder `../../public_html/file.php`.

`require_once` will insure no more than one call to that file is ran in an instance, so it's helpful to avoid mistakes!

Comment: I recomend using [require_once()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) and use parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you! That's usually how I do it. I edited original answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php include'../dbconnect.php'; ?>
```

Or you can also use:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dbconnect.php'; ?>
```